# Wait for all Operations in queue to finish before performing task

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an Operation subclass and Operation queue with maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1.

This performs my operations in a sequential order that i add them which is good but now i need to wait until all operations have finished before running another process.

i was trying to use notification group but as this is run in a for loop as soon as the operations have been added to the queue the notification group fires..  How do i wait for all operations to leave the queue before running another process?

```
for (index, _) in  self.packArray.enumerated() {

    myGroup.enter()
    let myArrayOperation = ArrayOperation(collection: self.outerCollectionView, id: self.packArray[index].id, count: index)
    myArrayOperation.name = self.packArray[index].id
    downloadQueue.addOperation(myArrayOperation)
    myGroup.leave()

}

myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
 // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Put the `myGroup.leave()` in the completion block for the operation.

Comment: Use waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue/1407971-waituntilalloperationsarefinishe

Comment: Please note: your queue is guaranteed to execute operations in submission order **only if** all operations in the queue have the same relative `queuePriority` and become ready in the order they were added to the serial queue. See the "Determine the Execution Order" section in the OperationQueue docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use operation dependencies to initiate some operation upon the completion of a series of other operations:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()

let completionOperation = BlockOperation {
    // all done
}

for object in objects {
    let operation = ...
    completionOperation.addDependency(operation)
    queue.addOperation(operation)
}

OperationQueue.main.addOperation(completionOperation)  // or, if you don't need it on main queue, just `queue.addOperation(completionOperation)`
```

Or, in iOS 13 and later, you can use barriers:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()

for object in objects {
    queue.addOperation(...)
}

queue.addBarrierBlock {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // all done
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clean.  Thanks

Comment: Hey Rob, I've done exactly this but my `completionOperation` is still being prematurely fired. My operations are asynchronous network operations so an operation is only considered `finished` when the response comes back. I read that I need to override the `isAsynchronous` property among a few others to make it an asynchronous operation, but I read that the property will be ignored if I add the operation to a queue anyway. So I'm confused on what to do. Could you please advise further?

Comment: what if there is an array of operations in a loop and I wanna wait for all of theme

Comment: I don’t know what you mean. That’s what the above does, waits to fire the completion operation until they’re all done.

Comment: Re `isAsynchronous`: It is true that `isAsynchronous` is ignored when adding to a queue, but all of the `isExecuting`, `isFinished` and the associated KVO is required when adding operations that wrap some asynchronous process to a queue. That having been said, I believe it is best practice to set `isAsynchronous` to `true` when the operation is, indeed, asynchronous, to (a) reflect the reality of the operation and  (b) to ensure it works whether it is used in a queue or just manually started.

Comment: Regarding the operation dependencies technique here, it looks like `main` is a class var on `OperationQueue`? Should that line be changed to `OperationQueue.main.addOperation(completionOperation)`? Does that have the same implications?

Comment: @hgwhittle good catch. Both approaches work for the completion operation pattern (but barrier approach only works on the designated queue). Adjusted answer accordingly.

Comment: @Pavan maybe you can check my answer on this.

Answer (score 8):

A suitable solution is KVO

First before the loop add the observer (assuming `queue` is the `OperationQueue` instance)

```
queue.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"operations", options:.new, context:nil)
```

Then implement

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if object as? OperationQueue == queue && keyPath == "operations" {
        if queue.operations.isEmpty {
            // Do something here when your queue has completed
            self.queue.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"operations")
        }
    } else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

In Swift 4 it's much easier

Declare a property:

```
var observation : NSKeyValueObservation?
```

and create the observer

```
observation = queue.observe(\.operationCount, options: [.new]) { [unowned self] (queue, change) in
    if change.newValue! == 0 {
        // Do something here when your queue has completed
        self.observation = nil
    }
}
```

Since iOS13 and macOS15 `operationCount` is deprecated. The replacement is to observe `progress.completedUnitCount`.

Another modern way is to use the KVO publisher of `Combine`

```
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

cancellable = queue.publisher(for: \.progress.completedUnitCount)
    .filter{$0 == queue.progress.totalUnitCount}
    .sink() { _ in 
       print("queue finished") 
       self.cancellable = nil           
    }
```

Comment: the `operationCount` property was deprecated. Does that mean it *shouldn't* be used?

Answer (score 3):

I use the next solution:

```
private let queue = OperationQueue()

private func addOperations(_ operations: [Operation], completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [unowned self] in
        self.queue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: true)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the maximum number of concurrent operations to 1

```
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
```

then each operation will be executed in order (as if each was dependent on the previous one) and your completion operation will execute at the end.

Comment: Just be careful here: this only holds if all operations in the queue have the same relative `queuePriority` and become ready in the order they were added to the serial queue. See the "Determine the Execution Order" section in the `OperationQueue` docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue)

Answer (score 0):

**Code at the end of the queue**
refer to [this link](https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/11/25/code-at-the-end-of-the-queue/)

NSOperation and NSOperationQueue are great and useful Foundation framework tools for asynchronous tasks. One thing puzzled me though: How can I run code after all my queue operations finish? The simple answer is: use dependencies between operations in the queue (unique feature of NSOperation). It's just 5 lines of code solution.

**NSOperation dependency trick**
with Swift it is just easy to implement as this:

```
extension Array where Element: NSOperation {
/// Execute block after all operations from the array.
func onFinish(block: () -> Void) {
    let doneOperation = NSBlockOperation(block: block)
    self.forEach { [unowned doneOperation] in doneOperation.addDependency($0) }
    NSOperationQueue().addOperation(doneOperation)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to that of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42496559/452115, but I don't add the `completionOperation` in the main OperationQueue but into the queue itself. This works for me:

```
var a = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 10)

let queue = OperationQueue()

let completionOperation = BlockOperation {
    print(a)
}

queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2
for i in 0...9 {
    let operation = BlockOperation {
        a[i] = 1
    }
    completionOperation.addDependency(operation)
    queue.addOperation(operation)
}

queue.addOperation(completionOperation)

print("Done ")
```

Answer (score -1):

I have met this problem, too. Well, instead of NSOperation, the GCD has already provide api: `dispatch_group`, for example:

```
dispatch_group_t myGroup = dispatch_group_create();

// task1
dispatch_group_enter(myGroup);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // excute task1
    // ...

    // task1 completed，leave group
    dispatch_group_leave(myGroup);
});

// task2
dispatch_group_enter(myGroup);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // excute task2
    // ...

    // task2 completed，leave group
    dispatch_group_leave(myGroup);
});

dispatch_group_notify(myGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // call back on all tasks c finished
    NSLog(@"all tasks are finished");
});

// continue other tasks.
```