# How to achieve DispatchGroup functionality using OperationQueue?

Tags: ios, swift

how to get notified when your async tasks are finished in OperationQueue?

Comment: For example with key-value-observing of the `operationCount` property.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495794/wait-for-all-operations-in-queue-to-finish-before-performing-task which contains an answer for @vadian as he mentioned in his comment :-)